# method to fetch entire tag list on archive.php

Tags: functions, conditional-tags, template-tags, tags

## What I have Tried →

```
<?php
    $taginto = get_the_tag_list();
    if ( ! empty( $taginto ) ) {
    echo '<a class="categum" href="' . esc_url( get_tag_link( $taginto[0]->term_id ) ) . '">'  . esc_html( $taginto[0]->name ) . '</a>';
    }
?>
```

## What I want →

> I am on www.somedomain/tag/apple/ and trying to display all tags like 
>   this: **there are some other tags that you can browse: tag list should
>   follow(excluding the one on whose page we currently are.)**

I am trying to display all the tags that exist, but miserably failed →

1. tag list not getting fetched
2. tags name not getting fetched

where am I wrong? what is the Fix?

Comment: [Read the Codex page, `get_the_tag_list` returns a string, not an array of objects](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tag_list). You probably want something more like `get_the_tags`.

Comment: sir, I tried that also, but it is populating just one tag not all. If i am here → www.somedomain/tag/apple/  then it will print just "apple"

Comment: If you want all tags, not just the ones attached to a specific post, use `get_tags`. The example on that codex page shows you how to use it, your code currently outputs just the first element of the returned array.

Comment: It worked for me. Will you write an answer? Is there any way we can exclude the one tag on whose page we are there.for example → `www.somedomain/tag/apple/` apple should not be printed.